# BizTalk error executing the send pipeline

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am getting the following error for BizTalk:

> SendUpdated_XML_Invoice 
>   There was a failure executing the send pipeline: "ABC_BizTalk.SendPO_NEWXML, ABC BizTalk, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=447e6d27f458459f" Source: "XML assembler" Send Port: "SendUpdated_XML_Invoice" URI: "C:\Integrations\FApps XML Invoices\%MessageID%.xml" Reason: The document type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/Edifact#Efact_Contrl_Root" does not match any of the given schemas.

I am not sure how to solve this error. I tried researching on it and trying different solutions but didn't work out.

Comment: The message sent in this port is not matching with the schema defined. Try to validate the message that you are sending with the schema that you are using in this port to see where the validation error is.

Comment: How can I check this? Please can you tell me everything in details as I am new to it.

Comment: You need to put a breakpoint in the Orchestration Debugger and get the message before send it. Save the message in your local. In Visual Studio open the schema and add the route where you saved the message in the property Input Instance Filename. Right button over the schema and press Validate Instance. Results of validation will appear in output window.

Comment: biztalk searches for schemas by the namespace and root node name in combination.  It looks like "namespace#RootNodeName". It's the blue text in your example. Open the biztalk management console and expand "All applications". Then look in schemas and search for the combination your error message gives. You might need to add a reference to the application with your edifact schema

Comment: I sent the EDIFACT file ..It goes through and then the xml file fails. I have XML file and the XSD but don't know whats wrong. I tried validating the file using tools but couldn't find the cause.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that BizTalk cannot find a schema with the targetNamespace and root name given in the error.

This schema should exists in the BizTalk EDI Application and only there.
You can check this via the BizTalk administration console and looking in  and sorting by Target Namespace.

[image]

If you see more that one schema with the same namespace and root node, that would cause issues, you need to remove it from your application

Comment: Why did you remove the remark about having to reference the EDI application?

Comment: @Ehssan  I remembered that Schema's aren't actually isolated per application, so I don't think you need to reference the EDI application.  Am I incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Efact_Contrl_Root is a control message check the UNB segment for partners (sender) you should be able to find the message amongst suspended message using Biztalk Administration

You have a request for ACK set in the UNB segment of you edifact or your trading partner is sending an control

If you are not expecting an Ack disable it